# Livewire Wire Elements Modal not triggering events

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using Wire Elements Modal, It is working properly but events are not getting triggered from modal component. My modal is like below

```
class AddUser extends ModalComponent
{
    public function render()
    {
        $this->emit('refresh');
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('contentChanged');
        return view('add-user');
    }
}
```

In above component two events are emitted and below code listens to them. But below code is not triggered at all. If I use normal Livewire component then below code is triggered without any issue.
The problem is only if I use WireElements/modal component.

In layout file I have listener like below

```
<script>
        Livewire.on('refresh', () => {
           //code
        })
        window.addEventListener('contentChanged', (e) => {
            //code
        });
</script>
```

This works in normal livewire component but not in modal.

Comment: Your question is slightly vague. What is the expected behaviour? That some JS is executed each time the modal element renders?

Comment: When do you want this code to run? On the initial mount of the component?

Comment: Initial mount as well as subsequent requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial render will not handle emits or browser events since at that point there isn't even a rendered document. What you can do is use [wire:init](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/defer-loading#introduction), to trigger your events in the first render:

```php
class AddUser extends ModalComponent
{
    public function render()
    {
        $this->sendEvents();
        return view('add-user');
    }

    public function sendEvents()
    {
        $this->emit('refresh');
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('contentChanged');
    }
}
```

```html
<div wire:init="sendEvents">
    
</div>
```

I have tested this myself and it triggers each request cycle.